# is there alternate way to install Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I couldnt able to install Scrapy through pip (pip install Scrapy) through my corporate network.

Is there any alternate way to download and install Scrapy?
appreciate you help.

Comment: what is problem you are facing in installation of scrapy using pip.

Comment: What's the error message? Have you tried `pip install scrapy --user` and then checking your `~/.local/bin` ? Or spawning a virtualenvironment in your userspace and install it there?

Comment: Hi Usman, sorry for the late reply.below is the error msg its returning   "Collecting Scrapy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.url
lib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03313CB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/scrapy/"

Answer (score 0):

Download the zip file [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/archive/1.3.zip).

Unzip and change directory the terminal to the unzip folder

run `python setup.py install` to install scrapy.